# ¿Artículos/pronombres personales con preposiciones?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, preposiciones, artículos

(Primero, disculpa si no uso los términos correctos -- pongo esta pregunta parcialmente porque no sé cómo formularla para buscar la respuesta en otro lugar.)

Considerad una frase como esta:

> Él miraba la luz que entraba por la ventana; consideraba también las moscas que estaban pasando por **la** al mismo tiempo.

¿Es correcto esta **la**?  Por supuesto, la frase entera terminaría

> ...que estaban pasando por la ventana al mismo tiempo

Me suena raro la primera frase, pero es lo que quería escribir. ¿Es aconsejable usar un demostrativo en un contexto como este?

> ...que estaban pasando por esta al mismo tiempo

Y con un sujeto masculino, ¿cuál sería la formulación correcta? Si consideramos

> Él miraba el pájaro que volaba por el espacio; consideraba también las moscas que estaban volando por **el/él** al mismo tiempo.

¿usamos

> ...que estaban volando por el al mismo tiempo

o

> ...que estaban volando por él al mismo tiempo

?

Supongo que sería la segunda frase, por lo tanto pienso que quizás estemos aquí antes de pronombres personales....

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

(Una pregunta adicional: ¿es correcto *por* aquí, o debe/puede ser *a través de*?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu confusión es entre **artículos** y **pronombres personales**. Los artículos definidos son *el, la, los, las*. Quizá la confusión provenga de que tres de los artículos definidos (*la, los, las*) son idénticos a pronombres personales. Esto ocurre porque provienen del mismo origen en latín. Pero aunque se escriben y dicen iguales, tienen funciones totalmente diferentes.

Los pronombres personales vienen en tres **casos gramaticales**: nominativo, acusativo y dativo. El nominativo se usa para el sujeto de la oración, el acusativo para el objeto directo y el dativo para el objeto indirecto. Además los pronombres personales en acusativo y dativo vienen en dos versiones: **tónicos** y **átonos**. Tónico significa que tiene acentuación propia y funciona como una palabra separada. Átono significa que no tiene acentuación propia y se une a una palabra vecina (aunque a veces se escriba separado).

**Detrás de las preposiciones se usan pronombres personales tónicos** (que son iguales en acusativo y dativo). Estos pronombres son *mí, ti, él/ella, nosotros/nosotras, vosotros/vosotras, ustedes, ellos/ellas*.<sup>1</sup> Como ves hay diferentes pronombres para los dos géneros en la tercera persona del singular y en todas las del plural (salvo *ustedes*). Entonces decimos:

- *pasando por la ventana* = *pasando por **ella***
- *volando por el espacio* = *volando por **él***

En vez del pronombre personal de tercera persona se puede usar el demostrativo, pero a veces no suena bien, o suena muy formal o extraño. Depende del contexto.

A tu pregunta extra, sí, se puede decir *a través de* en lugar de *por* en estos casos.

<sup>1</sup> También existe un pronombre de tercera persona singular reflexivo tónico, *sí*, que suele ir acompañado de *mismo*, y un pronombre personal neutro, *ello*, que es más usado en el discurso formal.

Comment: Gracias. Muy buena explicación. La pena es que sabía esto -- "por ella"" --pero no lo he usado hace tiempo. Parece que recordó lo de  "por él" pero mi mente se congeló con "por ella" Gracias!

Comment: "-pero no lo he usado _desde_ hace tiempo"

Answer (score 1):

Tu confusión, creo, se debió a que "el" cumple dos funciones gramaticales diferentes.  Simplificando un poquito tu ejemplo:

> El pájaro volaba por **el** espacio; los mosquitos volaban por **él** también.

Te fijaste que "el" se usa como artículo pero también como objeto de la preposición "por".  Notando esta redundancia, se te olvidó que el caso femenino no tiene esta redundancia.  Ahí sería **ella**:

> Él miraba la luz que entraba por la ventana; consideraba también las moscas que estaban pasando por **ella* al mismo tiempo.

Hé aquí la tabla:

(yo) ............ mí
(tú) ............. tí
(él) ............. él
(él) ............. ello [*it*]
(nosotros) .. nos
(vosotros) .. vos
(ustedes) ... ustedes
(ellos) ........ ellos
(ellas) ........ ellas

Para mí, la manera más fácil de recordar estos pronombres es con la frase *pasar por* _____ .

Por ejemplo: ¿Cómo voy a llegar al concierto mañana?  Si mis tíos me van a recoger en auto, entonces se puede decir

> Mis tíos van a pasar por mí.

Pero *ello* no puede ir a un concierto.  **Por ello** (es decir, por esa razón), hay que usar otro ejemplo: *por ello*.